# Need to make minigame auto run itself...I have no idea to solve it

Tags: python, selenium

http://zzzscore.com/memory/

### If you go into the link, you will see a minigame.
I need to make this minigame do it by itself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver')
driver.get('http://zzzscore.com/memory/')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
def find_click():
    picture1 = btns[0].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture2 = btns[1].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture3 = btns[2].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture4 = btns[3].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture5 = btns[4].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture6 = btns[5].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture7 = btns[6].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture8 = btns[7].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture9 = btns[8].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture10 = btns[9].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture11 = btns[10].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture12 = btns[11].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture13 = btns[12].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture14 = btns[13].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture15 = btns[14].value_of_css_property('background-color')
    picture16 = btns[15].value_of_css_property('background-color')

    for btn in btns:
        if picture1 == picture2:
            btn[1].click()
            btn[5].click()
            break


time.sleep(3)

# finding buttons
btns = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#body > div')

# looking <span>'s class
for b in btns:
    val = b.find_element_by_css_selector('span').get_attribute('class')
    print(val)
while True:
    find_click()
```

---

I just need to make the minigame run itself
But I don't know how to do it my mental is broken..
Seriously you don't have to do this becuz I know I'm bad in coding and so bad in English
Plz just tell me how to solve this Thing if you don't mind your time

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following. Get all span texts by waiting for the elements to load. Then do a for for loop to click similar values.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
driver.get("http://zzzscore.com/memory")
images = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='grid x4']//span")))
#for image in images:
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')",image)
for i in images[:-1]:
    for j in images[1:]:
        if i.get_attribute('class')==j.get_attribute('class'):
            i.click()
            j.click()
        #print(i.get_attribute('class'),j.get_attribute('class'))
```

A more difficult but faster way would be to remove indexes instead of O(n^2).

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```